# Change log level of Geckodriver for Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

It appears `Selenium 3.0` and above requires `geckodriver` with Firefox under Python 2.7., which I now have installed. However, it appears that running Selenium with Firefox now automatically creates the file `geckodriver.log` in the directory running the Python script.

I'd like to stop this from happening. I've looked around at various Github threads looking for an answer, but can't find anything for Firefox for Python. What I could find in `geckodriver --help` is to set the log level to any of the following:

> ```
>    --log <LEVEL>
>         Set Gecko log level [values: fatal, error, warn, info, config, debug,
>         trace]
> ```

However, I'm not sure how to do this. Perhaps using something like `desired_capabilities` or `service_args` for `webdriver.Firefox()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just hit trouble trying to increase this log level, but the easiest way to stop it log anything is to redirect to /tmp (or even /dev/null):

```
webdriver.Firefox(log_path='/tmp/geckodriver.log')
```

Answer (score 4):

This did the trick for me icw geckodriver 0.19.1

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

opties = Options()
opties.log.level = 'trace'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=opties)
```